# Is it possible to "overload" a generic class by using different type list?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

What I want is actually something like this:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    // ...
}

public class Foo<T, S> {
    // ...
}
```

Note that the name of the classes are the same, but the length of type list is different. The code above doesn't work in Java, but I hope it shows my intent. Is it possible to do similar thing in Java?

Example:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public Integer call(T input) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Foo<T， S> {
    public S call(T input) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No you can't do that. A class can only take either `single` or `double` generic type parameters, but not both. There is no overloading defined for this case.

Comment: Thank you - it seems I have to use a different class name.

Comment: Your intent is not so clear. Needs further explanation with examples with usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't override classes, you override methods. Classes might be subclassed.

This is possible:

```
public class Zoo<T, S, U> extends Foo<T>
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure OP meant overload instead of override.

Comment: @RohitJain I thought like that too, but needed to clarify it once more.

Comment: Well, you can replace override with overload and answer is still valid.

Comment: Oh yes - I did mean overload and I edited my question. Anyway the class name has to be different.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are trying to do:

Class foo1.Foo:

```
package foo1;

public class Foo<T, S> {
    public S call(T input) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Class foo2.Foo:

```
package foo2;

public class Foo<T> extends foo1.Foo<T, Integer> {
    public Integer call(T input) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be class Foo<T, S> and class SubFoo<T> extends Foo<T, Integer> ?

Comment: I edited my example to reflect the changes you made in your example. Is that what are you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to make a class such that, if I use SubFoo<String>, it should be exactly the same as Foo<String, Integer>. I think the way to do this is to let SubFoo<T> extends Foo<T, Integer> and leave the class body empty. I was trying to unify the names of the two classes but it seems to be impossible now.

Comment: Yeah, I finally understand. So I updated the example once again, and even tried to have both classes with the same class name (but in different packages)

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining a class as

`public class Foo<T> {
    // ...
}`

Technically we are telling the compiler to replace the Generic with a Object as T is unbounded.

When we define the class as

```
public class Foo<T, S> {
// ...}
```

Compiler will not know how to resolve this.